# Been using rand.int for a while and seeing unexpected results

Tags: python, random

I've been running some code for an hour or so using a rand.int function, where the code models a dice's roll, where the dice has ten faces, and you have to roll it six times in a row, and each time it has to roll the same number, and it is tracking how many tries it takes for this to happen.

```
success = 0
times = 0
count = 0
total = 0

for h in range(0,100):
    for i in range(0,10):
        times = 0

        while success == 0:
            
            numbers = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        
            for j in range(0,6):
            
                x = int(random.randint(0,9))
                numbers[x] = 1
        
                count = numbers.count(1)
            
            if count == 1:
                success = 1
            else:
                times += 1
    

        print(i)
        total += times
        success = 0


    randtst = open("RandomTesting.txt", "a" )
    randtst.write(str(total / 10)+"\n")
    randtst.close()
```

And running this code, this has been going into a file, the contents of which is below
https://pastebin.com/7kRK1Z5f
And taking the average of these numbers using

```
newtotal = 0
totalamounts = 0

with open ('RandomTesting.txt', 'rt') as rndtxt:  
    for myline in rndtxt:              ,
        newtotal += float(myline)
        totalamounts += 1

print(newtotal / totalamounts)
```

Which returns `742073.7449342106`. This number is incorrect, (I think) as this is not near to 10^6. I tried getting rid of the contents and doing it again, but to no avail, the number is nowhere near 10^6. Can anyone see a problem with this?

Note: I am not asking for fixes to the code or anything, I am asking whether something has gone wrong to get the above number rather that 100,000

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean with "This number is incorrect"?

Comment: This is pseudorandom. Check the documentation and change to real random :)  https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong, but the same position in the list being chosen six times is the same, is that not the same as rolling the dice six times and it landing on the same face. I believe that numbers.count(1) is counting the numbers of 1s in _numbers_ ,not count.

Comment: @Gergo Pseudorandom numbers are perfectly acceptable in statistical contexts, just not for crypto.  PRNGs are preferred for non-crypto purposes specifically because of their speed and reproducibility (which useful for both debugging and confirmability by independent researchers) while being indistinguishable from real randomness based on statistical testing.  Use of a PRNG is not going to be the source of the problem here.

Comment: @BoarGules Why does this not look like the correct way to check for successive rolls?

Comment: @BoarGules When it rolls the dice, it will change one of the elements to a 1. This is our first roll. On the second roll, it changes one of the elements to 1. If this happens ten times, our dice has landed on the same face ten times in a row, and if it has landed ten times in a row, there should only be one `1` in the list, hence `numbers.count(1)`. Does this explain it?

Comment: @pjs you are right. random should be enough in this case. If he gets same seed he will have more frequently the same result.

Comment: @Gergo "If he gets same seed he will have more frequently the same result." Only if he keeps re-seeding, in which case he's misusing the concept of seeding.  Unless you really know what you're doing and want to play games with so-called variance reduction via correlation induction schemes, you should only seed a PRNG one time in your program.

Comment: @pjs What I'm saying is that if it rolls the same number, it will change the _same_ one leaving the amount of `1`s  as one. Though I don't know about the sampled dice rolls bit.

Comment: The answer to your added note is given as point 1 in my answer - the code you wrote doesn't perform the task you described. it's solving a completely different problem, so it will give a completely different answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues working against you here. Bottom line up front:

1. your code doesn't do what you described as your intent;
2. you currently have no yardstick for measuring whether your results agree with the theoretical answer; and
3. your expectations regarding the correct answer are incorrect.

I felt that your code was overly complex for the task you were describing, so I wrote my own version from scratch.  I factored out the basic experiment of rolling six 10-sided dice and checking to see if the outcomes were all equal by creating a list of length 6 comprised of 10-sided die rolls. Borrowing shamelessly from BoarGules' comment, I threw the results into a set—which only stores unique elements—and counted the size of the set. The dice are all the same value if and only if the size of the set is 1. I kept repeating this while the number of distinct elements was greater than 1, maintaining a tally of how many trials that required, and returned the number of trials once identical die rolls were obtained.

That basic experiment is then run for any desired number of replications, with the results placed in a numpy array. The resulting data was processed by numpy and scipy to yield the average number of trials and a 95% confidence interval for the mean. The confidence interval uses the estimated variability of the results to construct a lower and an upper bound for the mean. The bounds produced this way should contain the true mean for 95% of estimates generated in this way if the underlying assumptions are met, and address the second point in my BLUF.

Here's the code:

```python
import random
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np

NUM_DIGITS = 6
SAMPLE_SIZE = 1000

def expt():
    num_trials = 1
    while(len(set([random.randrange(10) for _ in range(NUM_DIGITS)])) > 1):
        num_trials += 1
    return num_trials

data = np.array([expt() for _ in range(SAMPLE_SIZE)])
mu_hat = np.mean(data)
ci = st.t.interval(alpha=0.95, df=SAMPLE_SIZE-1, loc=mu_hat, scale=st.sem(data))
print(mu_hat, ci)
```

The probability of producing 6 identical results of a particular value from a 10-sided die is 10<sup>-6</sup>, but there are 10 possible particular values so the overall probability of producing all duplicates is 10*10<sup>-6</sup>, or 10<sup>-5</sup>.  Consequently, the expected number of trials until you obtain a set of duplicates is 10<sup>5</sup>.  The code above took a little over 5 minutes to run on my computer, and produced `102493.559 (96461.16185897154, 108525.95614102845)` as the output. Rounding to integers, this means that the average number of trials was 102493 and we're 95% confident that the true mean lies somewhere between 96461 and 108526. This particular range contains 10<sup>5</sup>, i.e., it is consistent with the expected value.  Rerunning the program will yield different numbers, but 95% of such runs should also contain the expected value, and the handful that don't should still be close.

Comment: Bravo. I admire your approach of critiquing both (1) the algorithm and (2) the lack of a statistical basis for the expectation, and even more (3) your demonstration of the right way to do it. I have deleted my comments as not being in the same league as your answer. I wish the people who taught me my (now mostly forgotten) statistics had been as crisp.

Comment: @BoarGules I'm sorry you deleted your comments, they were definitely value added for me.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest if you're working with whole integers that you should be receiving a whole number back instead of a floating point(if I'm understanding what you're trying to do.).

`##randtst.write(str(total / 10)+"\n")` Original

`##randtst.write(str(total // 10)+"\n")`

Using a floor division instead of a division sign will round down the number to a whole number which is more idea for what you're trying to do.

If you ARE using floating point numbers, perhaps using the % instead. This will not only divide your number, but also ONLY returns the remainder.

`%` is Modulo in python

`//` is floor division in python

Those signs will keep your numbers stable and easier to work if your total returns a floating point integer.

If this isn't the case, you will have to account for every number behind the decimal to the right of it.

And if this IS the case, your result will never reach 10x^6 because the line for totalling your value is stuck in a loop.

I hope this helps you in anyway and if not, please let me know as I'm also learning python.